# Autoscaling: Instance starts and terminates abruptly [AWS]

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-cli

I am trying to create a complete system (using AWS CLI) of which autoscaling is a part.

when i add the autoscaling group the instance initiates, but after a cooldown period of 5 minutes (the default cooldown period) the instance automatically terminates, and this cycle keeps on repeating, though my threshhold is <= 0% CPU utilization  for the RemoveCapacity policy. i am not able to comprehend why this is happening ?

Below are the commands that i ran to create all the related Resources.

**Autoscaling group:**

```
aws autoscaling create-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name AWS-CoE-1-AutoScalingGroup --launch-configuration  AWS-CoE-1-AS-launch-config --max-size 3 --min-size 1 --desired-capacity 1 --health-check-type ELB --load-balancer-names AWS-CoE-1-LoadBalancer --health-check-grace-period 120 --vpc-zone-identifier subnet-153f2d53
```

**Scale out Policy**

```
aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --policy-name aws-coe-scaleout-policy --auto-scaling-group-name AWS-CoE-1-AutoScalingGroup --scaling-adjustment 1 --adjustment-type ChangeInCapacity
```

**Scale in Policy**

```
aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --policy-name aws-coe-scalein-policy --auto-scaling-group-name AWS-CoE-1-AutoScalingGroup --scaling-adjustment -1 --adjustment-type ChangeInCapacity
```

**Cloud Watch**
***: Alarm to AddCapacity***

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name AddCapacity --metric-name CPUUtilization --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistic Average --period 120 --threshold 80 --comparison-operator GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold --dimensions "Name=AutoScalingGroupName,Value=AWS-CoE-1-AutoScalingGroup"   --evaluation-periods 2 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-1:132895064974:scalingPolicy:03ff8c7b-cf7c-4d9b-970c-be7f4884415d:autoScalingGroupName/AWS-CoE-1-AutoScalingGroup:policyName/aws-coe-scaleout-policy
```

**Cloud Watch**
***: Alarm to RemoveCapacity***

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name RemoveCapacity --metric-name CPUUtilization --namespace AWS/EC2  --statistic Average --period 120 --threshold 0 --comparison-operator LessThanOrEqualToThreshold  --dimensions "Name=AutoScalingGroupName,Value=AWS-CoE-1-AutoScalingGroup" --evaluation-periods 2  --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-1:132895064974:scalingPolicy:6b3d9ba4-b4a9-472e-95f6-31fc0772ec33:autoScalingGroupName/AWS-CoE-1-AutoScalingGroup:policyName/aws-coe-scalein-policy
```

Also my alarm state remains `OK` through the entire initiation and termination of instances.

Comment: i was having the similar problems , check your instance `health check grace period` ! may be that is less, increase it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the instance comes online it must pass ELB health checks or it will be terminated by autoscaling. Does your launch configuration include userdata for instances to bootstrap themselves, or does the AMI your launching start up the web service automatically? If not, you need to configure this in order for Autoscaling to consider the instance to be healthy.

Refer to the [AWS docs on ELB health checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-add-elb-healthcheck.html).

Comment: your answer helped me, but the instance was being declared unhealthy by  ELB but the reason was different. As correctly mentioned by cryptic in comments to my question. Also i think keeping the stack overflow policy in mind, your answer should be a comment. Thnx :D